# Fetch Data From Database using AJAX in CodeIgniter

Tags: ajax, codeigniter

This code is not working in codeigniter when we get json array from database. 
How can we get data from database using ajax

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(window).on("load",function(){
    $.ajax({
        type:'ajax',
        url:'<?php echo base_url('index.php/user_control/showdata/'); ?>', 
        async:false,
        dataType:'json',
        success:function(data)
        {
//          console.log(data);
            var html='';
            var i; 
            for(i=0;i<data.length;i++)
            {
                html+='<tr>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].uname+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+data[i].email+'</td>'+
                        +'</tr>'; 
            }
            $(".showid").html(html); 
        },
        error:function(data)
        {
            alert('ajax error'); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: replace `type:'ajax',`  with  `post` or `get` like `type:'post',` and show your controller also

Answer (score 2):

this is all of you need

1.Controller:

```
class Ajax extends CI_Controller
{
    public function Users($id)
    {
        $this->load->model('User_mdel');
        echo json_encode($this->User_mdel->list());
    }
}
```

2.Model:

```
class User_mdel extends CI_Model
{
    public function list()
    {
        return $this->db->get('users')->result();
    }
}
```

3.View

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

</head>
<body>

<div class="container">          
  <table class="table table-dark table-striped" id="myTable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        $.get("<?php echo base_url('index.php/ajax/users/'); ?>", function (data) {

            var result = JSON.parse(data);

            $.each(result, function (i, item) {
                $('#myTable tbody').append('<tr><td>' + item.Firstname + '</td><td>' + item.Lastname + '</td></tr>');
            });
        });

    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and END

Comment: This should be picked as the correct answer, thank you Bahman rapsody